# CMAKE Esp32 using azure iot samples - what to check in into my repository

Tags: c, cmake, esp32, azure-iot-hub

I am really new to iot/embedded world (I come from the b2b java world). Currently I am starting setting up an ESP32 based project.
So far I tried esp-idf [Hello World example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/get-started/hello_world), went through [Platform IO tutorial](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/tutorials/espressif32/espidf_debugging_unit_testing_analysis.html?utm_source=docs.espressif.com) and tried the [Azure-IOT-Esp32-Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/tree/main/demos/projects/ESPRESSIF/esp32).
I would stick with the latter one because I got out of the box connection to azure and MQTT - this is what I need at the end.

As stated in readme I recursively checked out

```
cd iot-middleware-freertos-samples
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

What gives me a bunch of stuff. The question is what do I need to put into my repository?

- is it enough to check in all in `\iot-middleware-freertos-samples\demos\projects\ESPRESSIF\esp32`?
- what else I need to check in?

The goal is of course: if I clone this repo it should build out of the box - and download/clone/ generate all stuff needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it enough to check in all in \iot-middleware-freertos-samples\demos\projects\ESPRESSIF\esp32?

No, since you will need to have the libraries that are at the root of the github repo. Check for example the CMakeLists.txt file inside the folder `iot-middleware-freertos-samples/demos/projects/ESPRESSIF/esp32/components/azure-iot-middleware-freertos/`

It tells CMAKE to look for the libraries in the Root Path

```
set(ROOT_PATH
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../../..
)
```

So, you will need to check every CMakeLists.txt file in the ESP32 Project folder and decide what you can remove or not from the clone you did.

Comment: so the file i need are scattered around all directories?! This would mean that i need to fork the repo to create my project repo, right? or is there another practice to create an own project?

Comment: Exactly. Fork it and then use CMake to build the dependencies for your project.